# Sum of complex exponentials

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

I am working through a problem and part of it includes some finite exponential sums.  I get to this point where
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{N/r-1}e^{2\pi ijnr/N}=\frac{1-e^{2\pi ij}}{1-e^{2\pi ijr/N}} $$
Now my professor says I should be able to convince myself that when $ jr/N $ is an integer, this becomes $ N/r $. Otherwise it is 0.  I have not been able to convince myself of this. Maybe someone can help.  If $ jr/N $ is an integer, doesn't the denominator become $ 1-1 $?

Comment: Yes, and you should change of formula in this case.

Comment: Change the formula to what?

Comment: Your equation isn't clear. What is the upper limit of the sum? Is it $N/(r-1)$ or $(N/r) -1$? Nonetheless, you are correct that when $jr/N$ is an integer the denominator is $0$ on the RHS, but that just means the formula doesn't apply. The left hand side still makes sense when $jr/N$ is an integer.

Comment: Sorry, the upper limit is (N/r)-1.  Maybe I am just adding 1 N/r times?

Comment: It's not even clear what $N/r$ is. But sure, if $jr/N$ is an integer, and $N/r$ is an integer, then you are just adding $1$ $N/r$ times.

Comment: Okay.  Thank you!  It is very clear to me now.